# Python3.8--Cartopy/Fiona error: shapefile not recognized as a supported file format

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, cartopy

Running into trouble here making a simple plot with Cartopy.  Well, the issue suddenly arose out of a more complicated plot, but it comes down to simply having Cartopy ingest a shapefile of state boundaries.

Quick code snapshot:

```
#!/home/fewx/anaconda3/bin/python3.8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import cartopy
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([235., 290., 20., 55.])
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('110m'), linewidth=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('110m'), linewidth=0.5)

##Print default location of needed natural earth datasets
path = cartopy.config['data_dir']
print(path)

# Display the plot
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('cartopy_test.png')
```

The coastline shapefile plots perfectly fine, but I fail when trying to access the necessary state shapefile, 'ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp', with the error:

```
ERROR:fiona._env:`/home/fewx/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 83, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
  File "fiona/_err.pyx", line 291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer
fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: '/home/fewx/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plot_cartopy_contourf.py", line 35, in <module>
    plt.savefig('cartopy_test.png')
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 859, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2311, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 81, in print_figure
    super().print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2210, in print_figure
    result = print_method(
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1639, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 509, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 407, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 479, in draw
    return matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw(self, renderer=renderer, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2747, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/feature_artist.py", line 155, in draw
    geoms = self._feature.intersecting_geometries(extent)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/feature/__init__.py", line 302, in intersecting_geometries
    return super(NaturalEarthFeature, self).intersecting_geometries(extent)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/feature/__init__.py", line 110, in intersecting_geometries
    return (geom for geom in self.geometries() if
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/feature/__init__.py", line 287, in geometries
    geometries = tuple(shapereader.Reader(path).geometries())
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/io/shapereader.py", line 197, in __init__
    with fiona.open(filename) as f:
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/env.py", line 417, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 256, in open
    c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
  File "/home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 540, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
  File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 90, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
fiona.errors.DriverError: '/home/fewx/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Note that the parent zip file for 'ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp' does not exist in the corresponding directly, mainly because NACISCDN is down (again), and I needed to pull the files from github.

Any ideas what would cause this?  I'm a bit a newbie here...and this test code is running on a brand new conda-based installation of python that was built over the past week. Do I have incompatible versions of libraries (e.g. PROJ, GDAL, etc)?  This error has seem to come out of nowhere with this newer installation.

Thanks for you help!

UPDATE::
I had success plotting states, but I needed to physically plot the 'ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp' file that came in the cartopy_offlinedata package via Conda.  This required creating a new, independent feature via cfeat.NaturalEarthFeature(), and specifying which shapefile to use:

```
states_provinces = cfeat.NaturalEarthFeature(
        category='cultural',
        name='admin_1_states_provinces_shp',
        scale='110m',
        facecolor='none')

ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='black')
```

This makes me think I have corrupted shapefiles that I was trying to plot, causing the failure...but I won't know for sure until I can pull the full package down from NACISCDN--which is still down.

Comment: If you can update your Cartopy to the latest from conda-forge, the shapefiles should be downloaded from their new home at AWS.  See https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/1833, https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1849

Comment: Also I’m not sure you need “_shp” in your `name` keyword.

Comment: Thanks!  I updated to Cartopy 0.19, but did it through PIP.  I experienced the dreaded Conda-forge 'frozen solve' issues when attempting to update through Conda.  But I'll try again with a bit more patience.  It'd be awesome if future Cartopy releases came with the shapefiles included.  Having to go external for them creates....difficulties!

Comment: Cartopy v0.20 has now been released, so this issue should be resolved by upgrading to that, whatever your install method!